# What's restricting this while loop from working properly?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, while-loop

I feel truly ashamed to not be able to figure this one out but this is killing me! I don't understand why my while loop condition isn't working. Based on the range in the initial for loop, I'm getting a variable number of terms (above 10001) after crossing the 105000 for the second number in *range*.

```
prime = []

terms = 10001
length = 0

while length <= terms:

    for i in range(2, 110000): 
        isPrime = True

        for j in range(2, int(i**0.5) + 1): 
            if i%j == 0: 
                isPrime = False
                break

        if isPrime:
           prime.append(i)
    
    length = len(prime)

print(length)
```

And the output turns out to be

```
10024
```

I tried using len(prime) initially and then created the variable length, as expected, it made no difference.

Please nudge me in the right direction to fix this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not testing the `length` value against `terms` inside your outer `for` loop, so it will always return all the primes up to the end of the range. You need to add that check into that loop. For example:

```
prime = []    
terms = 10001

for i in range(2, 110000): 
    isPrime = True

    for j in range(2, int(i**0.5) + 1): 
        if i%j == 0: 
            isPrime = False
            break

    if isPrime:
       prime.append(i)
    
    if len(prime) == terms:
        break

print(len(prime))
```

Output:

```
10001
```

Note you can simplify your code (removing the `isPrime` flag) by taking advantage of an `else` clause on your `for` loop:

```
for i in range(2, 110000): 
    for j in range(2, int(i**0.5) + 1): 
        if i%j == 0: 
            break
    else:
       prime.append(i)
    
    if len(prime) == terms:
        break
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out to me. I'm now one more step familiar with python's nuances.

Comment: I was wondering how this else clause works when there isn't an if clause aligned to it at the top in the first place. Isn't that a necessary thing for an else statement? @Nick

Comment: @SachinKrishna no, in python a `for` loop can have an `else` clause; it is executed if there is no `break` from the for loop. See the [manual](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) it has an example just like your code